# Is it common that Uno clones misbehave when connected to 12v on VIN?

Tags: arduino-uno, power, clones

**Edit**: this was completely my mistake. See end.

My official Uno worked fine when powered by 12v on VIN, but my Uno clone acted really funny--it read random noise from an input when a simple wire was attached, but not with no wire. It was solved with a pulldown resistor. The worse problem was that the PWM didn't turn off when I called `analogWrite(pin, 0)`. More worrying, it seemed to be outputting by power rather than duty cycle, since my small LED strip seemed to be doing higher duty than my big LED strip (both powered by transistors), though both were being set with `analogWrite(pin, 0)`. I measured the 5v pin at 5.9v. The input voltage may have actually been up to 12.5 v, but clean. I disconnected VIN and hooked back up to USB, and everything worked fine.

I assume the solution is to either use a linear regulator wired to VIN, or a battery?

---

I did get the linear regulator, which didn't help. I finally checked all my voltages, and found there was a 0.8 volt difference between different grounds!  It turned out my breadboard was wired to the Arduino pin next to ground, instead of ground itself. I feel very lucky not to have ruined the board, and my only complaint is that the pins aren't labeled clearly as they are on my official Arduino. On the other hand, I wouldn't have been able to debug this as easily on the official Arduino, since the clone has lovely solder holes at each pin which are a great spot to stick a voltmeter probe.

Comment: you connected the uno clone to 12V without reading the specs for the board?

Comment: It may be naive of me, but I wasn't aware cheap clones had specs, at least specs that are in English. I thought they were supposed to work like the official ones, but with less reliable construction and components. Various internet sites indicate that clones max out at 12v while Arduino will handle 20v in a pinch, but I didn't think 12.3v (probably) would be over some hard limit.

Comment: `the solution is to either use a linear regulator wired to VIN, or a battery` - or stop using *cheap* chinese knock offs - I mean, clones :p

Comment: @JaromandaX You highlighted "cheap". Do you mean it's possible to find high quality knockoffs?

Comment: Clones. Yes off course

Comment: @JaromandaX I'd better ask a separate question about that. Are clones highly frowned upon in this forum? I live an hour from China, so I don't consider this to be an ethical issue like it might be for someone in the US or Italy. I mean, Arduino isn't marketed or priced for my demographic.

Comment: I'm not saying all chinese clones are poor quality either

Comment: I don't think there are any issues with discussing clones. This isn't the official Arduino website, and even there they have quite a lot of questions about clones, or indeed "home-made" boards which technically are nothing to do with Arduino, except that they might have an Atmega328P processor on them.

Comment: Have you tried to use `INPUT_PULLUP` mode on input pins? The CMOS circuits are basically high input impedance amplifiers and it catches all kinds of EMI.

Comment: @KIIV Thank you, is INPUT_PULLUP considered a best practice for using switches? That would save me a component. But it seems unlikely I would want a pulldown resistor on the base of an NPN transistor, right? The bad PWM output (going into the transistor bases) makes me think the board is going haywire, one step away from giving up the ghost.

Comment: For switches it's sufficient (maybe in environment with high interferences you'll have to use lower impedance). For driving NPN Base the OUTPUT mode is used and you have to use current limiting resistor (usualy about 1k).

Comment: i frown on using name-brand boards, but that's me; i like my money in my pocket.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it common that Uno clones misbehave when connected to 12v on VIN

Whether it is "common" is probably unanswerable unless you do some sort of survey.

However bear in mind that clones or "knock off" boards (some of which pretend to be official ones) are built to a price. The original Arduino was already designed to be cheap. To make them even cheaper the manufacturers may well make a number of compromises. For example, some use a cheaper USB interface chip. It wouldn't surprise me if the components like the voltage regulator, capacitors, etc. are under-specified.

I see from eBay that clones are already quite cheap, possibly around $US 4.50. To compete with that, some manufacturers may be cutting back even further on the quality of components.

---

> I assume the solution is to either use a linear regulator wired to VIN, or a battery?

You are probably better off bypassing the on-board regulator entirely. Get a wall-wart that outputs 5V **regulated**. The sort of thing that might power a USB-based device. Then plug that into the 5V pin of the Uno (not VIN). In fact, virtually any mobile phone charger wall-wart will output exactly what you want. Just run a USB cable from that to the USB port on the Arduino, and there you have it! Regulated 5V power.

---

The other thing that could work would be to give the voltage regulator a break. Don't put 12V into it, put in 9V. Then it doesn't have to work so hard (that is, dissipate the extra voltage as heat).

Comment: I'm just outside of China, so these clones were $2.70. They weren't even the cheapest I could have bought.

A wall wart is the worst and last option--this project has a fixed location, and it would mean running an additional long power cord to it. However, I should be able to get a linear regulator to output 5V from the (required) 12V that's being supplied.

I'm also thinking about making a voltage divider--the fluctuation shouldn't be that bad if I let 500 mA flow through the divider with no load. But please let me know if this is a bad idea.

Comment: To clarify, if I use a voltage divider, I would be supplying 9 V to VIN (letting the Arduino take care of fluctuation), but if I use a linear regulator, I'll apply 5 V to the 5V jack (assuming there is no fluctuation).

Comment: @piojo: The issue with the divider is that the voltage you get is highly dependent on the current you draw. Depending on what the Arduino is doing, the current draw can vary quite a bit.

Comment: Check out my [post about a temperature sensor](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12106) that runs from batteries. There are much better ways than trying to put 12V into VIN.

Comment: @NickGammon That mosfet technique is really interesting! As for my original post, I edited it to explain that the board wasn't the problem. I wired ground to a floating pin (next to GND) instead of GND. So the problem is between keyboard and chair, unless you blame the board manufacturer for labeling that's not as good as the labels on an official Arduino.

Comment: Some of the labelling on alternate boards is almost impossible to read (for me). I thought that was just my eyes. :)